# Place object class instead of generic type

Tags: java, selenium, reflection, collections, dynamic-binding

Is it possible to create a `List` storing elements, which are objects of class of another object? 
What I mean is: is it possible to make something like that, but with successful compilation?

```
private SomeRow row = getRow();  // method getRow returns 
                                 // different classes, which extends SomeRow

List<row.class> rows;  // how is it possible to make something like that?
```

The problem is that in Selenium WebDriver, which I am using, it is impossible to use wildcards, so it is forbidden to do like this `List<? extends SomeRow>`.

Does anybody have some ideas how to do this? Or tell me if it is impossible at all, please.

Comment: He wants subclasses as well; `List<SomeRow>` is more restrictive than `List<? extends SomeRow>`.

Comment: `row.class` is not giving you a type but a static instance representing the class. So you can't define a `List<Class<T>>` to add some instance of `T` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, not sure if this answer your question, how about

```
List <Object> rows;
```

then you could cast into appropriate class later using if , probably checking instanceOf the element